How to implement audio recording in background on iOS and Android using React Native with Expo?
I am developing a cross-platform application using Expo and React Native, targeting both iOS and Android. My goal is to enable audio recording that continues even when the app is backgrounded or the device's screen is locked. I prefer to find a solution that avoiding the need to eject and handle native code customization.
Currently, I'm using expo-av for basic audio recording functionalities, but without any background service implementation:
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

const startRecording = async () => {
  await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
    allowsRecordingIOS: true,
    playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
    staysActiveInBackground: true,
    interruptionModeIOS: InterruptionModeIOS.DoNotMix,
    shouldDuckAndroid: true,
    interruptionModeAndroid: InterruptionModeAndroid.DoNotMix,
    playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false,
  });
  const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync(
    Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY
  );
  await recording.startAsync();
};

const stopRecording = async (recording) => {
  await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
  return recording.getURI();
};

I understand the basic requirements like adding a background mode for iOS and using a Foreground Service for Android. However, I'm looking for guidance on maintained packages or combinations of packages that can handle these tasks within Expo's environment.
I’ve tried several libraries to enable background audio recording within Expo’s managed workflow, but so far haven’t found a solution that meets all the requirements.

expo-av: Provides basic recording, but lacks support for background/lock screen recording.
react-native-background-audio-record: Promising, but doesn't handle background recording reliably and appears outdated.
react-native-track-player: Suitable for background playback but lacks support for audio recording.

Questions:

How can I configure continuous audio recording in the background, including during lock screen?
Are there any maintained libraries or combinations of packages for this case?
If no single solution exists, what alternatives do I have within Expo?

I'm hoping to find a solution that leverages existing tools and libraries in Expo without resorting to custom native implementations. Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/ is an expo native background task manager; but from the quick scan of the docs I did not see any way to start a task from the app that will run in the background.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android but i think it only works for android

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-actions this looks promising but i've never tried. Please let me know if any of these works for u

For Ios, you need to update your infoPlist by adding
infoPlist: {
        NSMicrophoneUsageDescription:
          "The app records ...",
        UIBackgroundModes: ["audio"],
      }

to your config.ios
